# Why do Premier Lacrosse League teams not have a home city?

Tags: lacrosse

As far as I know, Premier Lacrosse League teams are not tied to a specific regional market. It is different from most professional sports leagues and teams.

What is the rationale and benefit of such a system?

I thought having a home city helps a team to have more loyal fans.

Comment: "I thought having a home city helps a team to have more [l]oyal fans." Citation needed.